# Questions about Truffle console and Truffle develop

Tags: truffle, truffle-console, truffle-develop

When I inputted `truffle console`, it showed the error:

```
➜  via-issuer-master truffle console --network interaction
truffle(interaction)> var cash = aw
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:773
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(binaryPayload) && binaryPayload.length > 125) {
^
TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
    at WebSocketConnection.pong (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:773:1)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:643:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

When I inputted `truffle develop`, it showed the error:

```
Error: The network id specified in the truffle config (5777) does not match the one returned by the network (1596182475756).  Ensure that both the network and the provider are properly configured.
    at Object.detectAndSetNetworkId (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:97:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Object.detect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:24:1)
    at Object.develop (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/environment/environment.js:74:1)
Truffle v5.1.35 (core: 5.1.35)
Node v12.18.2
```

Here is my configuration in truffle-config.js:

```
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
            port: 8545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
            network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
            websockets: true
        },
        interaction: {
            host: "127.0.0.1", 
            port: 9545,
        }
```

Why they happened and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**truffle-config.js** > *networks* section:

```
dev: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 7545,
  network_id: 5777,
  gas: 8000000,
  gasPrice: 2000000000,
  skipDryRun: true,
  websockets: true
}
```

It's default settings for `Ganache`. Therefore, first run the `Ganache` itself, and then execute:

```
$ truffle develop
```

*NOTE:* `ganache-cli` port defaults to **8545** (see [ganache-cli:options](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/blob/master/README.md#options)). `Truffle` by default configured for [Ganache App](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/quickstart#ganache-quickstart).

Comment: I have tried that many times. It still failed. I even run ganache-cli and then successfully compiled and deployed contracts, and then run ```truffle console``` or ```truffle develop```, the result is the same.

Comment: @Hsiang Answer is updated. See *NOTE* for more ditails.

Comment: Thanks. What about the issue whe I inputted ```truffle console```?

Comment: @Hsiang For this you need to provide settings from `truffle-config.js > networks > interaction`

Comment: I have added it in my question

Comment: @Hsiang To use `iteraction`, you need to run ethereum client first. Like `Geth` https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: Sure, I opend another window to run ganache-cli -p 9545 before used interaction

Comment: @Hsiang It's need to know `aw` value in `$ var cash = aw` expression